# How to link 2 different components from 2 different pages in React/MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 pages, first Appbar.js that I have my topside appbar and also a Navigation Menu Icon Button that when I press that, I want my Drawer (Material UI) in TempDrawer.js to show up.

It worked when I put all the codes just in Appbar.js file, but I want to link these two pages somehow to have button in Appbar.js but function and return in the TempDrawer.js.

That's because I called `TemporaryDrawer()` as a tag (`<TemporaryDrawer/>`) in another file.

Appbar.js :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';

    <IconButton
        size="large"
        edge="start"
        color="inherit"
        aria-label="menu"
        sx={{ mr: 2 }}
    >
        <MenuIcon />
    </IconButton>
```

TempDrawer.js :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';

export default function TemporaryDrawer() {

return (
      <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          open
          sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          [`& .MuiDrawer-paper`]: { width: drawerWidth, boxSizing: 'border-box' },
          }}
      >
          <Toolbar />
          <Box sx={{ overflow: 'auto' }}>
              <List>
                  {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                  <ListItem button key={text}>
                      <ListItemIcon>
                      {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                      </ListItemIcon>
                      <ListItemText primary={text} />
                  </ListItem>
                  ))}
              </List>
              <Divider />
              <List>
                  {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                  <ListItem button key={text}>
                      <ListItemIcon>
                      {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                      </ListItemIcon>
                      <ListItemText primary={text} />
                  </ListItem>
                  ))}
              </List>
          </Box>
      </Drawer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Very unclear to me what you want to achieve. Try to clarify your final goal. Also please show the parent component that calls AppBar and TempDrawer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Ivo , i updated codes and my final goal is that as i said i have one button in one page and have a function in another page, i want to press button in Appbar.js and activate a function in TempDrawer.js. is that even possible that i want?

Comment: Where is the function that invokes opening and closing of the drawer ?

Comment: I actually used MUI code in this link (https://mui.com/components/drawers/). I really don't know how to build functions this way... I really could use some help because it's a little bit confusing when i can't put a function inside the "export default function TemporaryDrawer() {" . . .
it won't work properly. @AppyMango

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am asuming you want to open drawer from App Bar or any other page and pass the function and state to it.
below is minimum working example.

**Appbar.js :**

```
import TempDrawer from "./TempDrawer";

export default function Appbar() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const ToggleDrawer = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={ToggleDrawer}>click me</Button>
      <TempDrawer open={open} ToggleDrawer={ToggleDrawer}/>
    </>
  );
}
```

**TempDrawer.js :**

```
export default function TemporaryDrawer({open,ToggleDrawer}) {
...
return (
    <Drawer
      open={open}
      variant="temporary"
      onClose={ToggleDrawer}
      ...
    >
    <Toolbar />
    <Button onClick={ToggleDrawer}>Close</Button>
    ...
 </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked very fine, but now another problem is that, in the reference code in (mui.com/components/drawers) we can click mouse (or we can say "mousedown" in react language) anywhere on the screen to close the Drawer. and now the only way to close the Drawer is to click on the Button again. is it even possible to do this without any anchor? because there is another anchor and AnchorEl that it's connected to another button and i'm afraid that when we push any of this two buttons, both drawer and menu open at the sametime.

Comment: Yes, it is possible please check the updated answer. I have added `onclose` method. check Api page for more info. https://mui.com/api/drawer/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really didn't see that prop.